# Hibernate 5 still ignores @Table annotation to find tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Does Hibernate still ignores the @Table name annotation? All my tables are named in CamelCase strategy. Is there any way to use the annotations or do I have to write my own naming strategy?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't find them ? Are you using a database which is case sensitive on table name ? is so use @Table('\"MyTableName\"")

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL as database.

Comment: I gather Spring sets some "naming strategy" and basically contravenes what the JPA spec defines for table and column namings. If you search on this site you'll find others with that. Using other JPA providers avoids this problem, or manually setting this property for Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

According to JSR 338, JPA 2.1

To specify delimited identifiers, one of the following approaches must be used:

• It is possible to specify that all database identifiers in use for a persistence unit be treated as delimited identifiers by specifying the  element within the persistence-unit-defaults element of the object/relational xml mapping file. If the `<delimited-identifiers/>` element is specified, it cannot be overridden.

• It is possible to specify on a per-name basis that a name for a database object is to be interpreted as a delimited identifier as follows:
• Using annotations, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by enclosing the name within double quotes, whereby the inner quotes are escaped, e.g., `@Table(name="\"customer\"").`
• When using XML, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by use of double quotes, e.g., `<table name="&quot;customer&quot;"/>`